# Resolve a conditional type from a generic type argument

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, conditional-types

Examples are better than words so lets start with that:

https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgPIAczAPYgM4A8AKshAB6QgAmeyAFAEbbYA2EcIyAPsgK7UQYoCFQCUAPmQBvAFDJkYAFzIS5SjQVReKAPzI8YKKADmAbQC6yZQaMhjAbjnJ0yoo4C+jmTH4IsuZBhmZGJSCghqWkZmNg5uPgEhEBEJOmxMHHxlDH98YnFRaScEXANpBQAaZ2R3ZABeZHTcvHtkGSdgGHp0Qtl5eTAAOiCoAFFEAAs6OgArQrrJPv75EvxWCEGWbGNZ0Udl9z2nWogWPBQlldL1ze26MCP5dxlPGSA

Is there any way for me to make the compiler understand that if the flow falls into the first condition, that `t` should be an array?

Comment: Please put your example as plain text in the question itself.   An external link is great, but someone shouldn't need to follow a link to understand the question.

Comment: As an answer to your question, though, the compiler can't do that kind of higher order analysis on generic conditional types like that, so it errs on the side of being cautious.  In your case the compiler is correct to complain, because someone can call `foo({ t: "foo", p: Math.random() > 0.001 })` like [this](//tsplay.dev/Nab9Pm).  Seems like you just want a discriminated union like [this](//tsplay.dev/WzAK3m) (which only works with destructuring in TS4.6+).  Not sure where you want to go with this as an answer, and whether the discriminated union is relevant or you just want a "no" answer.